# Homomorphism From Cyclic Group Of Order n To Set Of Elements Of Order n

Tags: group-theory

Problem:

Let $A$ be a group. Show that mapping $f \in \operatorname{Hom}(C_n,A)$ to $f([1]_n)$ gives a bijection between $\operatorname{Hom}(C_n,A)$ and the set of $a \in A$ of order dividing $n$.

Attempt:

I was thinking that maybe there is a way to do this using the First Isomorphism Theorem. If we consider $K = \ker(f)$, then there might be a bijection between the equivalence class $[1]_n$ in $\operatorname{Hom}(C_n,A)/K$ and $f([1]_n)$. I'm not exactly sure.

What approach should I take from here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- $f([1]_n)$ must be an element $a \in A$ satisfying $a^n = e$. That is, the order of $f([1]_n)$ in $A$ must divide $n$.
- Given some $a \in A$ of order dividing $n$, can you find some $f \in \text{Hom}(C_n, A)$ such that $f([1]_n) = a$?
- Any $f \in \text{Hom}(C_n, A)$ is uniquely characterized by the value $f([1]_n)$.